# Define an object and detect similar objects in the same picture

Tags: computer-vision

I need directions with regards to what kind of algorithms I should use to solve the following problem: Given a cropped out image (that belongs to the bigger image), find all similar objects in the bigger image.

[image: Detection Example]
I have searched around on google and found solutions such as template matching, and feature matching (i.e SIFT and ORB). May I request for your help to point me in the  right direction with regards to which algorithm I should be researching on? Thank you!

Comment: Your problem - assuming you didnt super-simplify it for SO - should be solvable by simply checking the pixel values in your favourite programming language. Detecting squares or rectangles is not very hard, and since you are not using photographs you have no noise to compensate. I'd recommend you look into openCV for image-loading and conversion to pixel-values, if you know a bit C/C++/python.

Comment: The problem is that the object to look out for is arbitrarily set by the user, in this case the algorithm needs to look out for squares but the markers can be of any shape, such as diamond and circles. The idea is to use a sample that is manually cropped by the user to identify the other markers.

It seems that simple template matching will not work as the markers are affected by the grid lines, the connecting lines within the marker, and other overlapping markers.